# Error when importing OpenCV python module (when built with Qt and QtOpenGL)

Tags: python, qt, opencv, import

I recently downloaded OpenCV 2.3.1, compiled with the CMake flags withQt and withQtOpenGL turned on. My Qt version is 4.7.4 and is configured with OpenGL enabled. Supposedly I only need to copy cv2.pyd to Python's site-package path:

> C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages

And in the mean time make sure the OpenCV dlls are somewhere in my PATH. However, when I try to call

> import cv2

in ipython, it returned an error:

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

I also tried OpenCV 2.3, resulting the same error. If OpenCV is compiled without Qt, the import works just fine. Has anyone run into similar problem before? Or is there anyway to get more information, such as which procedure is missing from what DLL?

Answer (score 0):

Probably need the qt dll's in the same place as the opencv dlls - and they have to be the version built with the same compiler as opencv (and possibly python)

Comment: In fact, I had all my Qt dlls built with the same compiler in the PATH, too. But that did not help. Thanks for the input though.